Read csv without filling up empty values
I have the following csv I want to read into Python (Spyder) and count the amount of blank values in column 2:



column 1
column 2




A
N/A


B
N/A


C
N/A


D



E
N/A


F
N/A


G



H
N/A



In this case, there are two blank values, the rest are default values.
The standard code is:
LoadFile=pd.read_csv(FileName)
Which reads in the data as:



column 1
column 2




A
NaN


B
NaN


C
NaN


D
NaN


E
NaN


F
NaN


G
NaN


H
NaN



So the empty count is 8, not 2
missings =LoadFile['column 2'].isnull().sum()

Then I tried to read it in as:
LoadFile=pd.read_csv(FileName,na_values='', keep_default_na=False)
Which changes the table into:



column 1
column 2




A
N/A


B
N/A


C
N/A


D
N/A


E
N/A


F
N/A


G
N/A


H
N/A



So the empty count is zero.
How do I read in my csv file so the empty count is 2 and it does not alter the empty values.

A csv file is a text file. Instead of showing the obtained dataframe, you should show the raw content of the file.

This works fine for me.
CSV = '''column 1,column 2
A,N/A
B,N/A
C,N/A
D,
E,N/A
F,N/A
G,
H,N/A'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(CSV), na_values='', keep_default_na=False)
df['column 2'].isnull().sum()
# 2

Alternatively, don't define na_values and count the blanks:
df = pd.read_csv(FileName, keep_default_na=False)
missings = df['column 2'].eq('').sum()

Output: 2

Not defining na_values worked.
